# Can someone help figure out my shoulder problem?

Tags: infection, diagnostics, cysts

I'm not really into medicine or anything, just have a quick question. So since I was younger, I had this shoulder cyst thing since maybe 1st grade or something and nobody could diagnose it. It basically just grows and shrinks randomly and whenever it grows, it basically hurts to do anything with that shoulder. I guess a heat pad helps but that's about it. Has anyone heard of something similar?